# How can I call Child function from Parent Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, components, react-props

Good day. I have three components. A **Master** Component, A **TopBar** and a **Child**  component (Refers to the rest of my application). The Master is a layout wrapper that nests the Child Component. The Top Bar component is used inside the Master Component so that it is constant througout the site.
The Challenge is that, when a button is clicked on the Top Bar, I want a function to be called inside the Child Component.

What is the best possible way to achieve this

**Master.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import TopBar from './TopBar'

const Master = (props) => {
    function handleFunc (childFunc) {
        setChildFunction(childFunc);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
              <TopBar onHandle={handleFunc}/>
              {props.children}
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default Master
```

TopBar.js

```
import React from 'react'

const TopBar = ({onHandle}) => {
  const childFunc = React.useRef(null)
    function handleClick (){
      childFunc.current();
      onHandle(childFunc);
    }

  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Click on Me</button> {/* Triggers the alert() function in Child.js */}
    </div>
  )
}

export default TopBar
```

Child.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Master from './Master'

const Child = () => {

    function alert(){
        console.log("This function is called when thew Top Bar Button is clicked");
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <Master>
            Child Contents
        </Master>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

What is the best way to achieve this.
I initially wanted to pass the ref object to the Master component so it can be passed down to the Child as shown above, but I keep getting errors (that "childFunc" is not a function).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pass the alert to master using props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your Child function to the Master component, then from the Master Component to TopBar component, that will cause props drilling but it will solve your problem,
Child.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Master from './Master'

const Child = () => {

    function alert(){
        console.log("This function is called when thew Top Bar Button is clicked");
    }
  return (
    <div>
        <Master func={alert}>
            Child Contents
        </Master>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Child
```

Master.js

```
import TopBar from './TopBar'

const Master = ({func}) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div>
              <TopBar func={func}/>
              {props.children}
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default Master
```

TopBar.js

```
import React from 'react'

const TopBar = ({func}) => {
  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={() => func()}>Click on Me</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TopBar
```

Comment: Tried this out. But it keeps giving "func" is not a function